# Mobile device detect, what I'm do wrong?

Tags: javascript

I use this code to detect mobile devices in order to show download buttons:

```
    function detectDevice() {
    var kindle = navigator.userAgent.match(/(Kindle|Silk|KFTT|KFOT|KFJWA|KFJWI|KFSOWI|KFTHWA|KFTHWI|KFAPWA|KFAPWI)/i) != null;
    var android = navigator.userAgent.match(/Android/i) != null;
    var iOS = (navigator.userAgent.match(/(iPad|iPhone|iPod)/g) ? true : false);

    if ( kindle)
    { 
    document.getElementById("android_btn").className += " hide"; 
    document.getElementById("ios_btn").className += " hide"; 
    }
            else if (iOS)
            { 
            document.getElementById("android_btn").className += " hide"; 
            document.getElementById("kindle_btn").className += " hide"; 
            }
                    else if (android)
            {
            document.getElementById("ios_btn").className += " hide"; 
            document.getElementById("kindle_btn").className += " hide"; 
            }
    { // do nothing...show both }
        detectDevice();
    }}
```

It doesn't show the right button for the right device it show both buttons for any device.

Comment: Doesn't work...how?

Comment: It show the both buttons for ios and android when I'm using android phone and same goes for ios.

Comment: Based on used ids, there are 3 buttons, but your comment is saying show both, what do you mean? Also why do you use an empty block there, I don't think that syntax is really intended. This block executes every time, even if any of the condition matches. You would probably want to use `else`, so it executes only if none of the conditions match.

Comment: yes cause I deleted the kindle button

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Beside missing `else` statement, you have to bind your function to a `onload` or `onclick` events for the code to work.

```
<body onload="detectDevice()">
```

EDIT:

example:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
 <head>
  <title>Document</title>
  <style>
  .hide { display: none; }
  </style>
  <script type="text/javascript">
  <!--
    function detectDevice() {
    var kindle = navigator.userAgent.match(/(Kindle|Silk|KFTT|KFOT|KFJWA|KFJWI|KFSOWI|KFTHWA|KFTHWI|KFAPWA|KFAPWI)/i) ? true : false;
    var android = navigator.userAgent.match(/Android/i) ? true : false;
    var iOS = (navigator.userAgent.match(/(iPad|iPhone|iPod)/g) ? true : false);
    if (kindle)
    { 
        document.getElementById("android_btn").className += " hide"; 
        document.getElementById("ios_btn").className += " hide"; 
    }
    else if (iOS)
    { 
        document.getElementById("android_btn").className += " hide"; 
        document.getElementById("kindle_btn").className += " hide"; 
    }
    else if (android)
    {
        document.getElementById("ios_btn").className += " hide"; 
        document.getElementById("kindle_btn").className += " hide"; 
    }
    else {
        alert("We don't support desktop yet!");
    }
}

  //-->
  </script>
 </head>
 <body onload="detectDevice()">
  <input id="android_btn" type="button" value="Android Download" onclick="">
  <input id="ios_btn" type="button" value="IOS Download" onclick="">
  <input id="kindle_btn" type="button" value="Kindle Download" onclick="">
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: @HASH717 calling this function like that won't work, do you call it from inside the function it self? I've updated mine, check the code

Comment: what if they connected from desktop?

Comment: Of course you can add `else` to check if they are connected from desktop, I've updated the code. And you are welcome.